# How to get checked icon into my progress bar

Tags: html, css

I'm quite new in front-end coding. I've just added a progessa bar into my web page by just copying the css for here http://kodhus.com/newsite/step-progress-bar-css-only. Now I need to replace the numbers in by balls into 'checked'-icons. I have one jpg-picture of a checked-icon, but none of my efforts to show it works:

```
.progressbar li:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  /*content:url('checked2.jpg');*/
  /*content: counter(step); */
  content: 'v';
  /*class: glyphicon glyphicon-ok;
  counter-increment: step;*/
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

I've tried to store my jpg into django root, static and in the templates directory, but nove of them works. Running the code above I get 'v' into my balls it appears to all of them.

Changing the above definition to

```
.progressbar li:before {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
content: '';
counter-increment: step;
line-height: 27px;
border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
display: block;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: white;
background: (https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTLB-KSrRyq61FczWe9AUdEdz2GJfs51oNKuiF_c3dfkRH23Ii9);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
/* z-index: 1111; */
}
```

I managed to get checked-icon into every circle (li-element).

But actually I just need to have only certain li-elements checked. 
I tried the following in jquery but it didn't work at all (it seemd to draw a new circle instead of modifying the existing one and the checked-image did not fit in the circle any more)

CSS before modifications:

```
.progressbar li:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  }
```

html:

```
    <div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
      <li id="first">login</li>
      <li id="second" class="active">choose interest</li>
      <li id="third">add friends</li>
      <li id="fourth">View map</li>
 </ul>
```

jquery to add checked-sign into the first li-element

```
$("#first").css('content',''); 
$("#first").css('background', '(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTLB-KSrRyq61FczWe9AUdEdz2GJfs51oNKuiF_c3dfkRH23Ii9)'); 
$("#first").css('background-size','cover'); 
$("#first").css('background-repeat-y','no-repeat'); 
$("#first").css('background-position','center center');
```

Comment: try to add position:absolute; and add parent div position:relative

Comment: Try using "the progressbar li" class. Then background-image: img url; If you have ur image located local into ur project you might need ./[img-name] instead of just [img-name]. The dot means 1 step back in url path and / is one step in front. If its more then 2 steps back use complete url of img. From C/D drive.

Comment: plz make a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Nvm sorry for my comment, Forget the progressbar li class. U did the right one. About the background-image, use content: url(); like you do, but in the same way as I explained with background-image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.progressbar li:before {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    content: '';
    counter-increment: step;
    line-height: 27px;
    border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTLB-KSrRyq61FczWe9AUdEdz2GJfs51oNKuiF_c3dfkRH23Ii9);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    /* z-index: 1111; */
}
```

**Note remove extra styles.**

Comment: Thanks for your answers and comments, the backgroud-image with content : ' ' worked.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine! please accept my answer and up-vote if it help's you Thanks

Comment: Using the CSS above I managed to insert the 'checked-icon' into every state circle in my progressbar, but I didn't manage to insert it just to some of them.

Comment: You can use `:nth-child(n)` of Css for targeting different child

Comment: I didnt get you point can you eleborat what you need . What dies that mean you need it on some items?

Comment: just modifed the question. Hopefully it helps in getting my point. And thaks for your patiency!

Comment: I would suggest you rather then giving style form jquery. just make a class which have styled check icon just add it to the completed steps. like `#first class. addClass('active')`.and in your styles `.progressbar li.active:before{}` and check icon in it. may be that would help

Comment: Yes may be, because  i don't know how it become so complicated although its so simple, Anyhow if you need more help in that case we are here to help you.

Comment: Just got it working. Actually using the idea already suggested by @Awais: In css: .progressbar li.checked:before {..} and then in jquery   $('#first').addClass('checked');